# Where to download the HERE Mobile SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, here-api

This could be the most stupid question, but I swear I cannot find where and how to download the Mobile SDK on the HERE website.

I only found where to [download the documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/versions)

Also, what is the difference between the Hybrid and the Online version of the sdks?

Answer (score 3):

Correct, The SDK is only available for Download by contacting the Here Team currently.

The  Basic difference between Hybrid and Online would be Offline capability with Hybrid version whereas Online requires an Internet connection always.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to contact them a week ago, but they didn't answer. Do you work for HERE? Can you please forward my request to them? I wrote them today too.

Comment: Now the SDK are available for evaluation and download from the Developer portal itself, go to the following link https://developer.here.com/plans/mobile-sdk

Answer (score 2):

On this link at the bottom https://developer.here.com/native-apis

> Platform Availability
>
> HERE Mobile SDK is available for Android and iOS platforms, for Business and Mobile OEM customers, the HERE Mobile SDK for Tizen is exclusively licensed to Mobile OEMs. For more information or to receive access to the HERE Mobile SDK please [contact us](https://developer.here.com/contact-us).

Seems like you have to contact them before you can use their SDK

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the below link to download Here maps mobile SDKs for android and iOS:
   https://developer.here.com/plans/mobile-sdk
2. Hybrid version will work both online and offline modes whereas online version will only work in online mode. You can download the maps with Here mobile SDK and then you can navigate to the places without internet. In hybrid version app will switch to offline automatically whenever net is not available.

Note: Currently there are two types of mobile SDKs are available

1.Starter Evaluation(90-day free trial) : We cannot download maps with this. Hybrid mode will not work here.

2.Premium Evaluation(90-day free trial) : We can download maps.